# How to check the Internet connection in android when WIFI is On but No Data Connection?

Tags: android, android-wifi

Hi I am getting app crash when i hit server from app, because my mobile is connected to Wifi hotspot of other mobile, in that mobile data is disabled and if i check the connection status of wifi it will return true so i allow to hit server and my app crashes...
Tell me how to handle this type of scenario.

Comment: You dont use a Connection Timeout mechanism? Or the response returned by webserver? Or the  Http Connection status code?

Comment: Fix the bug that's causing your app to crash.

Comment: hi tell me how to find that our wifi having internet connection or not

Comment: There is no fast way to tell if you have an internet connection that doesn't route very much data to some particular place on the internet.

Comment: thank you for your comments

Comment: And even if everything **is** working, **your** server (or the one you're trying to connect to) might be down/unreachable, so -- as others suggest -- you **must** fix your code so that it doesn't crash if it gets no response.  Whether that's by setting a timeout and examining return codes, or catching and handling exceptions depends on how you're accessing your server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check if your internet is working fine

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            try { 
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
                urlc.connect();
                return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
            } 
        } else { 
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
        } 
        return false; 
    }
```

make sure you don't run this code on the main thread, otherwise you'll get a NetworkOnMainThread exception (in Android 3.0 or later). Use an AsyncTask or Runnable instead.

Comment: hi i already tried this one this will take too long to check the status